# Create a shortcut for Preview to add new text box with certain border color

Tags: preview, shortcut

I am using the Preview app in my classes to write notes over PDF slides presented by professors. There is one operation that I do repetitively:

- add Text (in the Markup Toolbar)
- choose Border Color to be certain shade of magenta
- type my note.

I would have absolutely loved this app if the first two operations could be automated and assigned to a certain shortcut. But so far I could create a shortcut only for the first step (Keyboard » Shortcuts » App Shortcuts » +).

Is there a way to create shortcut for choosing the Border Color type in the Preview app?

Comment: What version of macOS are you using?

Comment: **Preview** does have **⌃⌘T** to add a **Text Box** for annotations; however, it only has basic scripting abilities, which does not include the ability to automate all the actions you've mentioned. I tried recording the actions in **Automator**, but playback was not totally successful. [**Skim**](https://skim-app.sourceforge.io) has extensive **AppleScript** support and you might be able to, using **AppleScript** and **Automator**, to create a **Service/Quick Action** that could be assigned a keyboard shortcut to automate the process. I don't have time to look into it further at the moment.

Comment: @user3439894, thanks! This is an answer I would accept. (I am using Mojave.)